# Enter a valid date/time - Django Datetime Picker

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-forms, python-datetime

I'm creating a CRUD application in Django, and one of the fields in the data requires the user to enter a datetime input.  This was working smoothly until this evening when I started to work on it again, however I'm getting the below error when I try to add any data the the model.

> start_datetime
>
> Enter a valid date/time.
>
> [01/Dec/2022 00:34:39] "POST /activities/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2253

I've tried quite a few ways to resolve this but nothing seems to be working; below if the code I have to create the activity

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('name', 'start_datetime', 'end_time',
                  'location', 'town', 'description')
        labels = {
            'name': 'Activity Type',
            'start_datetime': 'Date & Time of Activity',
            'end_time': 'End Time',
            'location': 'County',
            'town': 'Town (optional)',
            'description': 'Description',
        }
        widgets = {
            'start_datetime': DateTimePickerInput(),
            'end_time': TimePickerInput(),

        }

class DateTimePickerInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'
```

This is the model field for the start_datetime:

> start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works smoothly in my test:

forms.py

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Activity
        fields = ('name', 'start_datetime', 'end_time',
                  'location', 'town', 'description')
        labels = {
            'name': 'Activity Type',
            'start_datetime': 'Date & Time of Activity',
            'end_time': 'End Time',
            'location': 'County',
            'town': 'Town (optional)',
            'description': 'Description',
        }
        widgets = {
            'start_datetime': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
            'end_time': TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        }
```

Django expects the following [datetime-input-formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats):

```
[
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
]
```